# Cordova/PhoneGap: can the user change the URL?

Tags: cordova

I have a rather dumb question whose answer I haven't found yet. Is there any actual way for the user to change the URL he/she is viewing? Of course we can change the URL by using links, JavaScript, etcetera, but what I want to know is whether the user can change the URL in a situation *outside the program's control*.

The reason I'm asking this is because I use GET parameters to send information to some of the pages in my Cordova app. So far I have been assuming that the user cannot change the URL and so I haven't been worrying too much about sanitizing the input, verifying that it's correct, etcetera, etcetera, since I already assure that it's all right when generating the URLs the user is going to work with. However, if the user can change the URL by himself in any way that I am not aware of, then much more effort needs to be put in sanitizing the parameters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, as long as you don't provide a way for the user to change the URL (links, JS, etc.) then they are not able to do so.

This is because the initial URL of the app is set in the native code and there is no way to inject a new URL into this setting.